# Sharepoint Timer Job Paused State

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have sharepoint timer job which will be paused, if I run the job manually it will work without any issue. This job is scheduled to run for every 1 hr, but some times it will work without any issue and some time it will struck for more runs.
Other jobs in the farm are running successfully without any issue, only for this job I am facing the issue.(The issue is in Prod environment Sharepoint 2013, enterprise version)
Is anyone have encountered similar issue?

Regards
 - 
Anand

Comment: The "Paused" state should be achieved by running while the timer recycle job is running. Otherwise the job should not enter it. Any clue why this job gets a request to shut down?

Comment: is that a custom timer job?

Comment: clear the server cache and check

Comment: Restart SharePoint Timer Service in Windows Service panel , you can check ULS log to see what block the timer job to run .

Comment: Yes its customer timer job. but other custom timer jobs are working as expected. Is there any way we can configure not to conflict with Timer recycle job.